# Uploading large file on server using laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, server

hello friends my website made on laravel framework I am trying uploading large video files which size more than 200mb but I am unable to upload large video file on server while on localhost `php.ini` I increase `max_file_upload` size and `post_max_size` working fine on localhost but on godaddy server I am unable to upload large file here my godaddy  config file

```
  memory_limit = 4048M
    max_execution_time = 3600
    max_input_time = 3600
    max_file_uploads = 7200
    extension=php_gd.dll
    upload_max_filesize =2048M
    post_max_size = 2048M
    FcgidBusyTimeout 1200
    FcgidIOTimeout 3600
    FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
    php_value memory_limit 2048MB
```

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Program;
    use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
    use Auth, Session, Str, DB, File, Image;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    
    class ProgramController extends Controller
    {
        private $directory = "main.program.";
        private $title_singular = "Program";
        private $title_plurar = "Programs";
    
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $title_plurar = $this->title_plurar;
            $directory = $this->directory;
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            $parent = isset($request->parent) ? $request->parent : NULL;
            $search =  isset($request->search) ? $request->search : "";
    
            $get_parent = NULL;
            $records = Program::where("level" , $level);
            if( !blank($parent) ){
                $check_parent = Program::where("public_id" , $parent)->first();
                $get_parent = $check_parent;
                if($check_parent)
                    $records = $records->where("parent_id", $check_parent->id);
                else
                    $records = $records->whereNull("parent_id");
            }
            else
                $records = $records->whereNull("parent_id");
    
            if( !blank($search) )
                $records = $records->where("title" , "LIKE" , "%$search%");
    
            $records = $records->orderBy("order_id", "asc")->paginate(30);
            
            return view($this->directory."index_level".$level , compact('title_plurar' , 'directory' , 'records', 'level', 'parent', 'parent', 'get_parent', 'search') );
        }
    
    
        public function create(Request $request)
        {
            $form_button = "Create";
            $directory = $this->directory;
            $title_singular = $this->title_singular;
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            $parent = isset($request->parent) ? $request->parent : NULL;
            return view($this->directory."create" , compact('form_button' , 'title_singular' , 'directory', 'level', 'parent'));
        }
    
    
    
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request,[
                'title'=>'required',
                'image'=>'required',
                'order_id'=>'required|numeric',
            ]);
    
            $record = new Program();
    
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            
            if( $level == 1){
                $this->validate($request,[
                    'description'=>'required',
                    'date'=>'required',
                ]);
                $record->description = $request->description;
                $record->date = Carbon::parse($request->date);
            }
    
            if( $level == 2){
    
                $this->validate($request,[
                    'description'=>'required',
                ]);
    
                $record->description = $request->description;
                if(isset($request->video_link) || isset($request->video)){
                    if(isset($request->video_link)){
                        $record->video_link = $request->video_link;
                        $record->video = NULL;
                    }
                    else{
                        $record->video_link = NULL;
    
                        $path = public_path('storage/programs_videos/');
                        File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
    
                        $file = $request->file('video');
                        $file_name = "/storage/programs_videos/". date("dmy_His").'_sound.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $save_file = date("dmy_His").'_sound.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
                        $path= $request->file('video')->storeAs('public/programs_videos/',$save_file);  
                        $record->video = $file_name;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    return [array("error" => "The video link / sound field is required")];
                }
    
                
                if(isset($request->pdf_link) || isset($request->pdf)){
                    if(isset($request->pdf_link)){
                        $record->pdf_link = $request->pdf_link;
                        $record->pdf = NULL;
                    }
                    else{
                        $record->pdf_link = NULL;
                        $path = public_path('storage/programs_pdf/');
                        File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
    
                        $file = $request->file('pdf');
                        $file_name = "/storage/programs_pdf/". date("dmy_His").'_sound.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $save_file = date("dmy_His").'_sound.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
                        $path= $request->file('pdf')->storeAs('public/programs_pdf/',$save_file);  
                        $record->pdf = $file_name;
                    }
                }
    
                
            }
    
            if(in_array($level, [1 , 2]) ){
                $parent = isset($request->parent) ? $request->parent : NULL;
                $get_parent = Program::where("public_id" , $parent)->first();
                if($get_parent && !blank($parent) )
                    $record->parent_id = $get_parent->id;
            }
    
            $record->public_id = (string) Str::uuid();
            $record->title = $request->title;
            $record->order_id = $request->order_id;
            $record->level = $level;
    
            if(isset($request->image)){
                $path = public_path('storage/programs/');
                File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
                $imagename = "/storage/programs/". date("dmy_His").'_image.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = public_path($imagename);
                Image::make($request->file('image'))->save($path);
                $record->image = $imagename;
            }
    
            $record->save();
    
            Session::flash('success', 'Created successfully');
            return true;
        }
    
    
        public function show($public_id , Request $request)
        {
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            $record = Program::where("public_id" , $public_id)->where('level' , $level)->first();
    
            if(!$record)
                return redirect("/program");
    
            $title_singular = $this->title_singular;
            $directory = $this->directory;
            $is_show = 1;
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            $parent = isset($request->parent) ? $request->parent : NULL;
            return view($this->directory."show" , compact('record', 'title_singular' , 'directory', 'is_show', 'level', 'parent') );
        }
    
    
        public function edit($public_id, Request $request)
        {
            $form_button = "Update";
            $directory = $this->directory;
            $title_singular = $this->title_singular;
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            $record = Program::where("public_id" , $public_id)->where('level' , $level)->first();
            $parent = isset($request->parent) ? $request->parent : NULL;
    
            if(!$record)
                return redirect("/program");
    
            return view($this->directory."edit" , compact('form_button' , 'title_singular' , 'directory', 'record', 'level', 'parent'));
        }
    
        public function update(Request $request, $public_id)
        {
            $this->validate($request,[
                'title'=>'required',
                'order_id'=>'required|numeric',
            ]);
    
            $level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
            $record = Program::where("public_id" , $public_id)->where('level' , $level)->first();
    
            if($record){
    
                if( $level == 1){
                    $this->validate($request,[
                        'description'=>'required',
                        'date'=>'required',
    
                    ]);
                    $record->description = $request->description;
                    $record->date = Carbon::parse($request->date);
                }
    
    
                if( $level == 2){
    
                    $this->validate($request,[
                        'description'=>'required',
                    ]);
                    $record->description = $request->description;
                    if(isset($request->video_link) || isset($request->video) || !blank($record->video_link) ||  !blank($record->video) ){
    
    
                        if($record->video){
                            $image_path = public_path($record->video);
                            if (file_exists($image_path))
                                unlink($image_path);
                        }
                        
    
                        if(isset($request->video_link)){
                            $record->video_link = $request->video_link;
                        }
                        else if(isset($request->video)){
                            $record->video_link = NULL;
        
                            $path = public_path('storage/programs_video/');
                            File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
        
                            $file = $request->file('video');
                            $file_name = "/storage/programs_video/". date("dmy_His").'_sound.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                            $save_file = date("dmy_His").'_sound.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        
                            $path= $request->file('video')->storeAs('public/programs_video/',$save_file);  
                            $record->video = $file_name;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        return [array("error" => "The video link / sound field is required")];
                    }
                    
    
    
                    if($record->pdf){
                        $image_path = public_path($record->pdf);
                        if (file_exists($image_path))
                            unlink($image_path);
                    }
                    if(isset($request->pdf_link) || isset($request->pdf)){
                        if(isset($request->pdf_link)){
                            $record->pdf_link = $request->pdf_link;
                            $record->pdf = NULL;
                        }
                        else{
                            $record->pdf_link = NULL;
                            $path = public_path('storage/programs_pdf/');
                            File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
        
                            $file = $request->file('pdf');
                            $file_name = "/storage/programs_pdf/". date("dmy_His").'_sound.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                            $save_file = date("dmy_His").'_sound.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        
                            $path= $request->file('pdf')->storeAs('public/programs_pdf/',$save_file);  
                            $record->pdf = $file_name;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $record->pdf = NULL;
                        $record->pdf_link = NULL;
                    }
    
                }
    
                if(isset($request->image)){
                    $path = public_path('storage/programs/');
                    File::isDirectory($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
                    $imagename = "/storage/programs/". date("dmy_His").'_image.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $path = public_path($imagename);
                    Image::make($request->file('image'))->save($path);
                    $record->image = $imagename;
                }
    
                $record->title = $request->title;
                $record->level = isset($request->level) ? $request->level : 0;
                $record->order_id = $request->order_id;
                $record->save();
    
                return [array("success" => "Updated Successfully")];
            }
    
            return [array("error" => "Updation failed")];
        }
    
        public $deletion_array = [];
        public function get_deletion_array($id){
            array_push($this->deletion_array, $id);
            $records = Program::where("parent_id" , $id)->get();
            if($records->count() > 0){
                foreach($records as $record){
    
                    if($record->image){
                        $image_path = public_path($record->image);
                        if (file_exists($image_path))
                            unlink($image_path);
                    }
    
                    if($record->video){
                        $image_path = public_path($record->video);
                        if (file_exists($image_path))
                            unlink($image_path);
                    }
        
                    if($record->pdf){
                        $image_path = public_path($record->pdf);
                        if (file_exists($image_path))
                            unlink($image_path);
                    }
    
                    $this->get_deletion_array($record->id);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public function destroy($public_id)
        {
    
            $record = Program::where("public_id" , $public_id)->first();        
            if($record){
                
                if($record->image){
                    $image_path = public_path($record->image);
                    if (file_exists($image_path))
                        unlink($image_path);
                }
    
                if($record->video){
                    $image_path = public_path($record->video);
                    if (file_exists($image_path))
                        unlink($image_path);
                }
    
                if($record->pdf){
                    $image_path = public_path($record->pdf);
                    if (file_exists($image_path))
                        unlink($image_path);
                }
                
                $this->get_deletion_array($record->id);
                Program::whereIn("id" , $this->deletion_array)->delete();
                return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Deleted Successfully");
            }
            else
                return redirect()->back()->with("error", "Deletion Failed");
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question might have a better chance of quickly being answered on [https://serverfault.com/](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: You can if you stream them. Posting such big files won't work. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: You would either FTP it or do it through the cPanel file manager

Comment: @DimitriMostrey but it working fine on localhost i am able uploaded large file on server using larvel

Comment: @A.ANoman Its movie like website i uploaded it from browse file using larvel

Comment: On localhost you will probably not have a memory issue. Things that worked on my testserver had to be tweaked in order to work on production. For out-of-memory reasons. The server memory tries to hold 200Mb of data, which it can't. Streaming bypasses this limitation.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey How i can resolve please tell me?

Comment: What is the code you have to upload the file(s)? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @DimitriMostrey wait i am uploading lt